# Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible matrices. Prove or disprove that $A+B$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices

I need help on this question. I know $A+B$ cannot be invertible, but I dont know how to prove it to my professor?

Comment: Let $A+B=0$ and done.

Answer (score 8):

Let $A=I$, $B=-I$, is $A+B$ invertible?

Also, consider $A=I$, $B=I$, is $A+B$ invertible?

Answer (score 2):

Like @SiongThyegoh said, there is no way to produce a general theorem. I would like to add some cases.

- $A$ and $B$ could be invertible but not $A+B$ (take $A=I_n$, $B=-I_n$)
- $A$ could be invertible,and $B$ not but $A+B$ is (take $A=I_n$, $B=0$)
- $A$ and $B$ could both be not invertible but $A+B$ could be:

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$B:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$